# Is there an easy way to add a summary under the headline to the home page in a blogdown theme?

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I'd love to include a summary under the headline for each of the headline links on my blogdown home page using the hugo lithium theme, but I'm not sure what file to alter to change the main index.html display (or what I would add). Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify the template file [`layouts/_default/list.html`](https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium-theme/blob/master/layouts/_default/list.html). You can use the [page variable](https://gohugo.io/variables/page/) `.Summary`, but personally I have never liked this variable. If you happen to dislike Hugo's automatic summaries, too, you may read [this post](https://yihui.name/en/2017/08/hugo-post-summary/) of mine for a more complicated but hopefully more meaningful approach.